# How to add a non-Gmail account to my Google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have a personal Google account, which I use for Google Calendar. Sometimes, I have calendar invites addressed to my work account, which is not hosted by Google.

Is there a way to manage (or at least read) my work account calendar from my personal Google calendar?

Comment: Is your work account calendar reachable by using a web browser?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else has had this problem recently, I have another solution. Through one's Google account they can access the Personal Info section where, under the Advanced Email Settings, they can add an alternate email address (non-Google work email address). This not only allows one to log in to their Gmail account with their work email address (using their Google password), but also allows them to view and accept invitations to events with their personal email account on behalf of their work email account.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but how do we see invitations on the gmail account? I have an associated e-mail account for which I receive google calendar invitations but I can't find a way to see them in my google account.

Comment: How exactly does it "allows them to view and accept invitations to events with their personal email account on behalf of their work email account." ? I added my work email address as an alternate email, but I still don't see my work calendar on my personal gmail calendar..?

Answer (score 3):

Share it (with your personal one) *or*  grab the iCal file, and import that into Google Calendar (You can take the Google Calendar iCal file and import to the work calendar too, if desired).

Comment: To clarify the "sharing". If you forward the email from your work email to your gmail email. Then on the gmail account, you can answer the invitation and it automatically creates a calendar event for it.
There may be some settings to allow or disallow such behavior in gmail though, so if you don't get it, it may be hidden behind some setting.